# Blend out certain paths in CircuitikZ

Tags: circuitikz

Is there a way to draw certain paths, but simply blend them out so they won't actually get drawn?

In the following example from texample (http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/power-electronics-converter-inverter/) I want to blend the path with C1 and the connection from C1 to up to the switch (until the "o" dot) out. However, I want the code to be still active, in case I need to use certain coordinates elsewhere!

Thank you.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[siunitx,european,fetbodydiode,smartlabels]{circuitikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
  % Generalized diagram of different components inside an AC drive with voltage intermediate circuit
% Based on a template by
% Author: Erno Pentzin (2013), http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/ac-drive-components/


\begin{circuitikz}
    \draw
    (0,0)
        to[V, l=$V_s$] ++(0,2.5)
        to[short] ++(1,0) coordinate (A)
        to[short] ++(0.5,0)
        to[L, l^=$L_1$, v=$v_{L_1}$] ++(1.5,0)
        to[short] ++(1,0) coordinate (B)
        to[short] ++(1,0) node[above] (C) {1}
        to[open, o-o] ++(0.65,0) coordinate (D)
        to[short] ++(0.5,0)
        to[L, l^=$L_2$, v=$v_{L_2}$] ++(1.5,0)
        to[short] ++(0.5,0) coordinate (E)
        to[short] ++(1.5,0)
        to[generic, v^=$~~V_o$] ++(0,-2.5)
        --(0,0)
    (A)                                         % Left of L1, top of switch A
        to[short] ++(0,-1.5) node[left] {2}
        to[open, o-o] ++(0,-0.5) node[left] {1}
        |- (0,0)
    (B)                                         % C1 connection starting from top
        to[C, l=$C_1$] ++(0,-1.75) coordinate (Aaux)
        -- ($(A |- Aaux) + (0.5,0)$)
        to[short, o-] ++(-0.5,-0.15)
    ($(C)!0.5!(D)$)                             % Switch B low connector
        ++(0,-0.5) node[left] {2}
        to[short, o-] ++(0,-0.1)
        |- (0,0)
    (D)                                         % Switch B blade
        to[short] ++(-0.65, -0.1)
    (E)                                         % C2 connection
        to[C, l=$C_2$] ++(0,-2.5)
    (B)                                         % Vc1
        to[open, v=$V_{C_1}~~$] (Aaux)
    ;
\end{circuitikz}


  \caption[Ersatzschaltbild]{Ersatzschaltbild}
  \label{fig:ersatzschaltbild}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: First, you need to put the circuit to be "blended" into a separate \draw command.  Then use \draw[color=white] to also make the components invisible.

Comment: what you mean with "blend up? make invisible? than just define only coordinates determined with this part and don't draw then lines and elements.

Comment: Also \draw[opacity=0] works, even when the background isn't white.